# MySQL Case switching with aliasing

Tags: mysql, switch-statement, case, alias

I'm trying to perform an SQL statement, that selects data from two tables in a schema, and matches certain values using aliasing. I am, however, having some difficulty in a case switching scenario, and need some help, please.

**Sample data from tables**

***Tbl1***

*Columns*: EID (as PK), station, co, duration, timestamp, direction, dialed

*Data*:

- 1006, 100, 14, 00:01:21, 2017-08-21 09:40:00, O, 1234567890
- 1007, 102, 14, 00:00:14, 2017-08-21 09:53:00, I, RING 00:05
- 1008, 105, 00, 00:00:45, 2017-08-21 09:57:00, E, 100

***Tbl2***

*Columns*: ext (as PK), user

*Data*:

- 100, Joe Soap
- 105, Sue Blossom

**The Query:**

```
SELECT log.EID, xtn.user, log.duration, log.direction, log.dialed,
    CASE WHEN log.direction = "E" THEN log.dialed = xtn.ext
         ELSE log.dialed = log.dialed END
from schema.tbl1 AS log, schema.tbl2 AS xtn
WHERE log.station = xtn.ext 

ORDER BY station asc;
```

**The Expected Outcome:**

- 1006, Joe Soap, 00:01:21, O, 1234567890, 1234567890
- 1007, Bob Caller, 00:00:14, I, RING 00:05, RING 00:05
- 1008, Sue Blossom, 00:00:45, E, 100, Joe Soap

**The Actual Outcome:**

- 1006, Joe Soap, 00:01:21, O, 1234567890, 1
- 1007, Bob Caller, 00:00:14, I, RING 00:05, 1
- 1008, Sue Blossom, 00:00:45, E, 100, 0

**Explanation to Problem:**

The **SELECT** query is supposed to take data from two tables, and case switch the *log.direction* column to check if it contains *"E"*, where it then should select the appropriate value by looking it up in the *xtn.ext* column, and show the *xtn.user* value accordingly.

When executed, it correctly identifies the station and replaces that column with the user, but it gives a logical 1 or 0 value in the column at the end (which shows that the logic is iterating correctly), but not the actual required data.

If the log.direction row value is E, it should lookup the username.
If the log.direction row value is anything else, it should show the original data of log.direction (until future implementation is added). The physical log.direction selection should be omitted, but was included for this sample to show how the demo should essentially operate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression is not valid because it is making an assignment.  The predicates of a `CASE` expression (i.e. whatever comes after `THEN` or `ELSE`) have to be singular *values*.  In any case, it appears that you are just trying to display one of possible two values depending on the value of the log direction.

```
SELECT
    log.EID,
    xtn.user,
    log.duration,
    log.direction,
    log.dialed,
    CASE WHEN log.direction = "E"
         THEN xtn.ext
         ELSE log.dialed END
FROM schema.tbl1 AS log
INNER JOIN schema.tbl2 AS xtn
    ON log.station = xtn.ext 
ORDER BY station;
```

By the way, you will note that I refactored your query to use an explicit join between the two tables.  This is the modern way of doing joins.

As a sidenote, you might wondering whence are the 0 and 1 values in your current output for the `CASE` expression.  My guess is that these are the return values of the assignments/comparisons you were making.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. With a minor tweak on the CASE...THEN line, I managed to get the expected result. Changed the xtn.ext to xtn.user. Kudo's for that explicit join!